# ansible playbook hangs when running via the cron

Tags: ansible

I have a ansible playbook that runs via the cron for every one hour and generates log. However, I have noticed from couple of days that the ansible playbook do not run and logs are not generated. After the cron has run, following process will be generated and it hangs the cron from running next time. When i run ps auxwww | grep ansible, it shows the following results

```
ansible  183974  0.0  0.1 323056 102296 ?       Sl   Jan21   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/sdf/bin/configs/ansible/hosts /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/site.yml
ansible  186154  0.0  0.1 323312 102820 ?       Sl   Jan21   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/sdf/bin/configs/ansible/hosts /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/site.yml
```

I will have to kill the above process and then the cron will run and the logs will be generated. Could anyone please let me know the raeson why the cron gets hanged.

Playbook has once again hanged as shown below

```
 ps auxwww | grep ansible-playbook

ansible  106974  0.0  0.0   4288   700 ?        Ss   04:10   0:00 /bin/sh -c /home/user/bin/crons/ansible/ansible-playbook_schedule.sh
ansible  106988  0.0  0.0  11180  2852 ?        S    04:10   0:00 bash /home/user/bin/crons/ansible/ansible-playbook_schedule.sh
ansible  135692  0.0  0.2 355576 159196 ?       Sl   Jan25   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/hosts /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/site.yml
ansible  138661  0.0  0.2 355576 159540 ?       Sl   Jan25   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/hosts /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/site.yml
ansible  141571  0.0  0.2 356088 160476 ?       Sl   Jan25   0:01 /usr/bin/python /usr/bin/ansible-playbook -i /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/hosts /home/user/bin/configs/ansible/playbooks/site.yml
```

Here is the link for cron [here](https://github.com/shettypriy/anisble-cron/blob/master/cron)

Comment: Hi user11549576, I hope you can appreciate that no one can _guess_ what is wrong without seeing your playbook or more code in general. You also could run ansible with higher verbosity to see for yourself what is happening. Please see the [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) page, and pay especial attention to the [MCVE section](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: @mdaniel i have provided the link for the cron . There is no issue with the ansible playbook that is used in the cron. It is the shell script that is hanging which I have provided in the link.

Comment: Your question very clearly says "playbook has one again hanged", implying it's a playbook issue, and I bet a playbook that has an action which tries to read stdin while running in cron will hang, but good luck with your question

Comment: sorry for the typo. It is supposed to be cron has hung once again

Comment: This typically happens when ansible is trying to get some sort of input from the user.  The most frequent case that I see this is when ansible tries to connect to a new server as a particular user for the first time, it may ask you to accept yes/no for the new server's host key.  Try running ansible manually from the server as the user account being used for the cron and make sure it is not requesting input.